# PyCharm - Is there a way to autocomplete DataFrame that has been read from a file?

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, pycharm

[image]

I've seen this question before, but no best answer, and the question was from 3 years ago.

Any chance I can use autocomplete for a panda DataFrame read from a file? (To access its columns)

Comment: How can you see the content of the df on the right?